# Is taking uint8 from user's input more efficient than taking uint64?

Tags: go, user-input, unsigned-integer

The following code takes a 64-bit unsigned integer from it's user's input:

```
package main

import  (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Give me a small integer?")
    scanner.Scan()
    times, _ := strconv.ParseUint(scanner.Text(), 10, 64)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", times) //real    0m1.900s user   0m0.000s sys    0m0.003s
}
```

and the following takes an 8-bit unsigned integer from it's user:

```
package main

import  (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Give me a small integer?")
    scanner.Scan()
    times, _ := strconv.ParseUint(scanner.Text(), 10, 8)
    times8bit := uint8(times) 
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", times8bit) //real    0m2.014s user   0m0.003s sys    0m0.000s
}
```

Both snippets take approximately the same amount of my CPU time(as shown in the comments by the result of `time`).

Is the second snippet using less memory than the first? I would think that creating another variable `times8bit` results in the second snippet using even more memory than that used by the first snippet. Is that the case? I am aware that the potential difference in performance is negligent, but is there another, a more efficient way of taking an unsigned 8-bit integer from user's input?

Comment: Such stuff doesn't warrant performance tuning.

Comment: "as shown in the comments by the result of `time`" - the programs spent 99.999% of this time waiting for you to read the prompt and finish the input.